# How to populate cells using VBA Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to populate a worksheet cells with some fields from another worksheet on the same workbook using VBA `Vlookup` and I'm stuck.

Worksheet users have the following data, column A contains the `Login` column B contains `Number`; it's empty but the goal is to populate it with data from another worksheet:

```
Login    Number
===============
ffff    
bbbb    
cccc    
dddd    
eeee    
aaaa
```

In the "Data" worksheet I've got the following:

```
Login    Number
===============
aaaa       1234
bbbb       1235
cccc       1236
dddd       1237
eeee       1238
ffff       1239
```

Currently I'm using this code

```
Sub VL()

    Dim Login As Range
    Set Login = Sheets("Users").Cells(2, 1) 

    Do Until Len(Login) = 0 'This will loop until the first empty cell
        Login.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                              Sheets("Users").Range("$A:$A"), [Table], 2, False)
        Calculate
        Login.Offset(0, 1).Value = Login.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Set Login = Login.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```

And the result isn't as expected:

```
Login    Number
===============
ffff      #N/A
bbbb
cccc
dddd
eeee
aaaa
```

I've searched on the forum but didn't find anything to help me solve this.

Comment: The cell references in a formula you supply `Range.FormulaR1C1` should  look like "R1C1"; this makes it easier than the "A1"-style reference, to build a cell reference with VBA code, as in `ref = "R" & row & "C" & column`, where "row" and "column" can be variables.

Comment: And +1 for an Excel question that's actually about *programming* with the Excel object model! Feel free to *accept* an answer that solves your problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub VL()
    With Sheets("Users").Range("A2", Sheets("Users").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        .Offset(, 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A" & .Row & ",'Data'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)"
        .Offset(, 1).Value = .Offset(, 1).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tiger,Thank you very much for your prompt help, this solve my issue. best regards

Comment: @Carlos, if this did indeed solve your issue, kindly accept it as the answer by clicking the checkmark.